# What is appWidgetIds[] for WidgetProvider? Why always get it's value 0?

Tags: android, widget, android-widget, appwidgetprovider

my simple code:

```
int[] appWidgetIds= AppWidgetManager.getInstance(getApplication()).getAppWidgetIds(new ComponentName(getApplication(), MyWidgetProvider.class));

        Toast.makeText(mContext,"ids:size:"+appWidgetIds.length,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        MyWidgetProvider myWidget = new MyWidgetProvider();
        myWidget.onUpdate(this, AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this),appWidgetIds);
```

I run it. but always i get appWidgetIds.length=0;
What is appWidgetIds for widget Provider. I am confused about this. If anybody help me. I am very helpful for this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`int[] appWidgetIds` is an array with app widget ids for referencing and updating them, e.g. inside `onUpdate` method of `AppWidgetProvider`. you are getting `length=0` probably because your app doesn't have any widget added to launcher

creating new `AppWidgetProvider` like you do

```
MyWidgetProvider myWidget = new MyWidgetProvider();
```

is inproper, you should declare it in manifest with

```
<receiver android:name="MyWidgetProvider">
    <!--filters here -->
</receiver>
```

[here you have some DOC](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html) how to deal with widgets